# error: invalid source release: 1.15 error: invalid source release: 15 | JDK 15

Tags: java, maven, sbt, java-15

what is the value of the source and target version with JDK 15

Build tool -> sbt/maven

i.e
`javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.10", "-target", "1.10")`

**Note:** Till 11 works fine

Comment: which springboot version you are using

Comment: what is your sbt version and what is your underlying scala version in use? here is a [jdk compatibility matrix](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-12-13-14-and-15-compatibility-notes) for reference. how else are you building the project, could you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of date on 3 fronts. Java is moving fast these days :)

- Java dropped the `1.x` scheme quite a while ago. It's just `15`, not `1.15`.
- Java *also* dropped the `-source` `-target` style. It's `release` these days.
- The java command line tools adopted posix style command switches, so, double up the `-`.

In other words, you're looking for `Seq("--release", "15")`.

Comment: 1. It's strange that OP says, till 11 it works fine(could SBT be using the same format but transforming before passing them to `javac`?). 2. any documents to support "Java also dropped..." statement? 3. Is this tested?